# PythonAnywhere SQLite/SQLAlchemy suddenly getting errors

Tags: mysql, sqlite, pythonanywhere

SQLAlchemy and SQLite errors appearing on PythonAnywhere but it was fine on localhost.
So I just uploaded my Flask site to pythonanywhere, and when I tried to access it it can't access my database, but is getting a bunch of errors instead.

```
2021-01-30 10:42:05,740: Exception on /m/550 [GET]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
**NO MATCH**
```

I was not getting these exceptions on my local computer. A little googling and it seems like this is because PA uses an older version of SQLite? Which seems a bit stupid to begin with but it also seems like I can't update it?

So I'm wondering if there is some smart solution to this, or if it would perhaps be easier to switch to MySQL? Would there be other problems in doing that instead? Or do I just need to switch out the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to fit MySQL instead? My Current one looks like this:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:////home/movieelo/cinelow/my_server/database/database.db'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

All help and guidence will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
I managed to switch to MySQL but am still getting SQL syntax related errors, such as:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in 
 your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
 version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY 
 movie_category_scores.category_id ORDER BY movie_category_scores.s' at line 2
 **NO MATCH**
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think that I have now identiefied the single function that is causing the errors, and it looks like this:

```
def get_top_movies_by_category(category_id):
    query = db.session.query(
    MovieCategoryScores,
    func.rank()\
        .over(
            order_by=MovieCategoryScores.score.desc(),
            partition_by=MovieCategoryScores.category_id,
        )\
        .label('rank')
    ).filter(MovieCategoryScores.votes >= 10)
    # now filter
    query = query.filter(MovieCategoryScores.category_id == category_id)
    query = query.order_by(MovieCategoryScores.category_id, 'rank')
    movies = query.all()
    return movies
```

Which generates this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/movieelo/cinelow/my_server/database/pers_movie_dbf.py", line 137, in get_top_movies_by_category
    movies = query.all()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3186, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3342, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3367, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1252, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT movie_category_scores.votes >= ? AS anon_1, movie_category_scores.movie_id AS movie_category_scores_movie_id, movie_category_scores.category_id AS movie_category_scores_category_id, movie_category_scores.score AS movie_category_scores_score, movie_category_scores.votes AS movie_category_scores_votes, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY movie_category_scores.category_id ORDER BY movie_category_scores.score DESC) AS rank 
FROM movie_category_scores 
WHERE movie_category_scores.votes >= ? AND movie_category_scores.category_id = ? ORDER BY movie_category_scores.category_id, rank]
[parameters: (10, 10, 11)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: Solution is touse the same version of python and sqlite on your dev computer as on the server.

Comment: @Shadow I just checked the sqlite3 version on both my computer and on pythonanywhere and they seem to be the same, so now I don't know what is causing the error, do you have any idea?

Comment: That syntax error looks strange, it's as if it's saying that SQLAlchemy is sending invalid SQL commands to SQLite, which is very unlikely.  Is there any indication in the error stacktrace of what the command that it is sending is?

Comment: Window functions were added [to SQLite version 3.25.0 (released 2018)](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#history), and [to MySQL 8.0.2 (released 2017)](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/).  It's possible that the version of SQLite and MySQL available on PythonAnywhere don't support them.  Can you provide the full query that SQLAlchemy is sending?  I would be helpful to figure out if there's an issue with the query itself.

Comment: @MaxShenfield I think I found the single function that is causing the errors, and I have updated the question with it.

Comment: It definitely looks like the problem is the `over` call in the query, then -- that's a window function.  Is there some other way to express the query you want to do without that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giles Thomas (of PythonAnywhere) [confirmed that the SQLite version available on PythonAnywhere doesn't support window functions](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/29148/#id_post_90176).

Window functions were added [to SQLite version 3.25.0](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#history).  In the future, you can check whether the SQLite version included with your Python installation supports windows functions by running:

```py
import sqlite3

if sqlite3.sqlite_version_info > (3, 25, 0):
    print("Window functions are supported!")
else:
    print("Window functions are not supported :(")
```

Comment: Yup thank you! Will look into if I can use Postgres instead (will my SQLAlchemy code work without needing to change anything if I migrate to postgres?) or having to use another service.